# Is there a way to concatenate __LINE__ and __COUNTER__ macros in c++

Tags: c++, macros

i tried this but it is not working :

```
#include <iostream>
#define CAT(A,B) A##B
#define MY_MACRO CAT(__COUNTER__,__LINE__)
int main(){
    std::cout<<MY_MACRO<<std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

it generates this error 
In function int main()
error  **COUNTER____LINE** was not declared in this scope

this too not helping :

```
#include <iostream> 
#define F1(x,y) x##y 
#define F2(x,y) F1(x,y) 
#define MY_MACRO F2(COUNTER,LINE)
 int main()
{
 std::cout<<MY_MACRO<<std::endl;
 std::cin.get(); return 0;
 }
```

it does not concatenate it just returnes LINE macro value and if you replace it in the code with an integer it will return that integer only not concatenated with COUNTER , so this question is not rellay duplicated

Comment: Format your code please

Comment: yes i did that now , it is halfly posted because connection is broken

Comment: Duplicate: Not the exact duplicate, but the issue is explained in detail in the answer.

Comment: i tried that too '#include <iostream>
#define F1(x,y) x##y
#define F2(x,y) F1(x,y)
#define MY_MACRO F2(__COUNTER__,__LINE__)
int main(){
    std::cout<<MY_MACRO<<std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
 return 0;
}

' but it is not working sorry "duplicated"  does not help me !

Comment: Well, what does "not working" mean?

Comment: it does not concatenate it just returnes __LINE__ macro value and if you replace it in the code with an integer it will return that integer only not concatenated with __COUNTER__